# How to know when enumerateTags function finished?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `enumerateTags` function of `NSLinguisticTagger` class for some string analysis. Everything works fine except one: I never know for sure when the enumeration is over.

```
let originalText = "Some text."
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage:"en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options:Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = originalText
tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSMakeRange(0, (originalText as NSString).length), 
scheme: NSLinguisticTagScheme.tokenType, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _, stop) in
    // I do my job here
    // I need to callback when the enumeration is over
    if tokenRange.upperBound == originalText.count {
        // Callback
    }
})
```

This end-checking works fine when the original string ends with a letter, but if it ends with a punctuation or a white space as in the example above, the callback never gets called.

I googled a lot but couldn't find any solution of this wide-spread, I believe, task: how to know for sure when the enumeration is over?

Comment: It has ended when  the `enumerateTags()`  function returns – why do you want to check that inside the closure?

Comment: Martin, are you sure this function is synchronous and you can safely rely on that the statement after the function is executed exactly after it returns? I'm a little bit nervous about treating blocks as synchronous part of code.

Comment: 100% sure. It would be documented otherwise (and  the callback parameter  would have to be `@escaping`)

Comment: Danke schön, Martin!

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the punctuation and white spaces, and thus the condition `if tokenRange.upperBound == originalText.count` will never be true if the text does end in a space or a punctuation.

You could work with this string instead of `originalText` inside of the language tagger:

```
let newText = originalText
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .punctuationCharacters)
```

Your code would look like this:

```
let originalText = "Some text  "

let newText = originalText
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .punctuationCharacters)

let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage:"en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options:Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = originalText
tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSMakeRange(0, (newText as NSString).length), scheme: .tokenType, options: options, using: {(tag, tokenRange, _, stop) in
    if tokenRange.upperBound == newText.count {
        print("reached the end")
    }
})
```

---

The callback starts with `in` in your code and not inside the if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

[`enumerateTags(in:unit:scheme:options:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger/2875124-enumeratetags) *synchronously* enumerates over the given ranges of the string and
calls the closure for each tag. The enumeration has finished when the function returns.

Asynchronous methods are (to the best of my knowledge) all *documented* as such,
take an `@escaping` closure as parameter, and allow to specify some kind of completion handler (or completion delegate method).

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
var finish: Void? {
     didSet{
      //do you want to do when enumerateTages finish 
     }
}

finish = tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSMakeRange(0, (newText as NSString).length), scheme: .tokenType, options: options, using: {(tag, tokenRange, _, stop) in
         //do something
}
```